# Showing no errors in VSlint?

Tags: javascript

I am using VS Lint, and the code does not function as I need it to.

Can anyone provide some advice as to what my script tag here should look like?

For context, this script comes after my form.

```
async function onFormSubmit(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const EL_form = ev.currentTarget;
    return (await fetch(EL_form.action)).json();
}
                                  
const ELS_form = document.getElementByID('element');

ELS_form.forEach((el) => 
    el.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
        onFormSubmit(
            const response = await fetch("/lookup/" + 'user input')
              .then(result =>result.json())
              .then(res => console.log(res));
    })
);
```

Comment: Can you add more context as to what you want to do. By the way, since you are using getElementById you don't need a forEach loop. there can only be one element with an id.

Comment: It isn't showing errors because the code is technically correct. Knowing what you want vs what you designed isn't one of its features.